# InvalidOperationException You must set this property to a non-null value of type string

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

The XX property on 'Table' could not be set to a 'Byte[]' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'.

I didn't create the mapping myself, this was generated from a db first scenario.  I am not inserting anything to a table, I'm just performing a select, this shouldn't happen at all?  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Sounds for me that the column in the DB table is of type `varbinary` but the corresponding property in the model class is of type `string`. Can you take a look at the types in model and in DB?

Comment: We cannot help you without details about your database and model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue but for byte to bool

I edited my entity
public byte XX { get; set; }
Then edited my Model to have 
public bool XX { get; set; }

used auto mapper to map them together and it fixed the issue i was having, try this with editing your Model to a string and map it accordingly.

i am using code first for my existing databases, but it may work for db first